# linq .net with dynamically generated controls

Tags: linq-to-sql

This is a very strange problem and i really dont have a clue whats causing it.

What is supposed to happen is that a call to the BLL then DAL returns some data via a linq SPROC call. The retunred IMultipleResults object is processed and all results stored in a hashtable.

The hashtable is stored in session and then the UI layer uses these results to dynamically generate some gridviews.

Easy you would think.

But if i run the code i dont get any gridviews.  If i take out the call to the BLL and DAL the gridviews appear but with nothing in them?

Why is it the page renders correctly when i take out the call to get the data?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your dynamic code called from the page pre render or the page load?

Comment: The controls are dynamically created on a button click.

It is essentially a search function.  User enters some details and they click 'find'.  System goes off to get search results and the results are displayed in dynamcically generated gridviews.

Comment: Um, breakpoint?  Set one between paragraph 2 and 3 and find out why your objects aren't being processed.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting an empty result set, you can configure the grid view to display something when no results are found.

I suggest you do some debugging and verify whether the code is actually getting the results and if it is being added the same way as int the other scenario.